# Are all prime ideals in a Dedekind domain also principal ideals?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose I have a domain that is not a principal ideal domain $R$, and I have a non-principal prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. Then $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has a maximal ideal given as
$$I=\left\{\frac{x}{y} | x\in\mathfrak{p},y\notin\mathfrak{p}\right\}$$
This is a maximal ideal because:

1. It's closed under multiplication: If $\frac{x}{y}\in I$, then for any $\frac{x'}{y'}$ with $y'\notin\mathfrak{p}$, $xx'\in \mathfrak{p}$ since it's an ideal, and if $yy'\in\mathfrak{p}$, then since $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, one of $y,y'$ would have to be in $\mathfrak{p}$, but we know both of them are not.
2. It's closed under addition:If $\frac{x}{y},\frac{x'}{y'}\in I$, then $\frac{xy'+yx'}{yy'}\in I$ since $xy'+yx'\in \mathfrak{p}$ since it's an ideal, and $yy'\notin\mathfrak{p}$ by the same logic as before.
3. Everything not in $I$ is a unit, and for any $\frac{x}{y}\in I$ and $\frac{x'}{y'}\notin I$, $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x'}{y'}=\frac{xy'+x'y}{yy'}$. Since $xy'\in \mathfrak{p}$, then if $xy'+x'y\in \mathfrak{p}$, then $x'y\in \mathfrak{p}$. But neither $x'$ nor $y$ are in $\mathfrak{p}$, and since it's prime, their product cannot be either. Thus, the numerator is not in $\mathfrak{p}$ so it is a unit of $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

Since $I$ is basically just the localization of $\mathfrak{p}$ by $R\setminus\mathfrak{p}$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is not a principal ideal, then won't $I$ also not be a principal ideal?

Since $I$ must be principal for $R$ to be a Dedekind domain, then can we conclude that if a ring $R$ is a Dedekind domain then there are no prime ideals that are not principal?

Comment: There are plenty of non-principal prime ideals in Dedekind domains. In fact, a domain having all primes principal is necessarily a PID.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560493/what-is-an-example-of-a-dedekind-ring-that-is-non-principal

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168082/an-integral-domain-whose-every-prime-ideal-is-principal-is-a-pid) are some proofs of the fact that a ring is a PID if and only if it is a domain and all prime ideals are principal.

Comment: You are making the incorrect conjecture: non-principal ideals may have a principal localization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, $R = \mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a Dedekind domain but isn't a PID since $$ 2 \cdot 3 = (1 + \sqrt{-5})(1 - \sqrt{-5})$$ represents a non-unique factorization.

So now let us look at the prime ideal $\mathfrak p = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$. This is not principal (as explained in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/560583/437127) that user26857 linked to) but its localization, $\mathfrak p R_{\mathfrak p}$, is generated by $1 + \sqrt{-5}$, because

$$ 2 = \frac{6}{3} = \frac{(1 - \sqrt{-5})}{3}(1 + \sqrt{-5}) \in (1 + \sqrt{-5})R_{\mathfrak p}. $$

On the other hand $2 \notin (1 + \sqrt{-5})R$ since

$$ \frac{(1 - \sqrt{-5})}{3} $$

is not an algebraic integer (its norm is $2/3$).

Answer (score 8):

In a Dedekind domain $R$, if all prime ideals are principal then all ideals in $R$ are principal since all (nonzero) ideals in $R$ are products of (nonzero) prime ideals. And many Dedekind domains are not PIDs, since otherwise concepts like the ideal class group of a Dedekind domain would be pointless to define.

An extreme illustration of what can be said on the theme you raised is that Zorn's lemma implies in an *arbitrary* commutative ring, if all prime ideals are principal then all ideals are principal (see Theorem 3.6 and the exercise following it [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/zorn1.pdf)). So in a ring with some nonprincipal ideal there is a nonprincipal prime ideal.

As Crostul points out in a comment, a ring with nonprincipal ideals can have a localization in which all ideals are principal.  In fact, for a Dedekind domain $R$ its localization at every prime ideal is principal and Dedekind domains are not always PIDs. The whole point of localizing a Dedekind domain at a prime is that it makes the structure much simpler, e.g., all ideals are now principal (and in fact all nonzero ideals in the localization are powers of the maximal ideal).